# error while sending location lat and long to the server

Tags: android

```
public void onLocationChanged(Location loc)
{

    GeoPoint point = new GeoPoint((int)(loc.getLatitude() * 1E6),
                      (int)(loc.getLongitude() * 1E6));

    String Text = "My current location is: " +
        "Latitud =" + loc.getLatitude() + "Longitud =" + loc.getLongitude();

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
               Text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    double x = loc.getLatitude();
    double y = loc.getLongitude();
    try {
        outToServer.writeDouble(x);
        outToServer.writeDouble(y);
    } catch(IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    mc.animateTo(point);
}
```

I already open socket on my first activity, then click next. Here is my second one, I want to send the lat and log data to the server.

```
05-31 02:05:41.055: DEBUG/StatusBarPolicy(180): [GPS ICON] GPS_ENABLED_CHANGE_ACTION or GPS_FIX_CHANGE_ACTION
05-31 02:05:41.125: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6365): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-31 02:05:41.125: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6365): java.lang.NullPointerException
05-31 02:05:41.125: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6365):     at yaraby.y.yarab$MyLocationListener.onLocationChanged(yarab.java:354)
05-31 02:05:41.125: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6365):     at android.location.LocationManager$ListenerTransport._handleMessage(LocationManager.java:191)
05-31 02:05:41.125: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6365):     at android.location.LocationManager$ListenerTransport.access$000(LocationManager.java:124)
05-31 02:05:41.125: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6365):     at android.location.LocationManager$ListenerTransport$1.handleMessage(LocationManager.java:140)
05-31 02:05:41.125: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6365):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-31 02:05:41.125: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6365):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
05-31 02:05:41.125: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6365):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4633)
05-31 02:05:41.125: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6365):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-31 02:05:41.125: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6365):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
05-31 02:05:41.125: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6365):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:858)
05-31 02:05:41.125: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6365):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
05-31 02:05:41.125: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6365):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: @hohi, how did you initialize `outToServer`?

Comment: DataOutputStream outToServer;

Answer (score 1):

`DataOutputStream outToServer` is `null`. You need to create the stream.

```
Socket socket= new Socket(<IP>,<PORT>); 
DataOutputStream outToServer = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
```

Comment: But i create it on the first activity must  it created on the second

Comment: My guess is that you have an instance variable named outToServer that belongs to respective class. If you create the stream in activity 'A' you can't just use it in activity 'B', it will be null.

Comment: But since i already created the socket on the first activity how can it be done to create a socket on the next activity ??